# Specifying quiver vector color by density

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have some vectors with defined position and orientation. I could show them in space by using the below code:

```
theta = [pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2];
r = 0.25; % magnitude (length) of arrow to plot
x = [4,3.5,3.75,4.5,8,10,12]; y = [8.5,8.2,8.3,8,9,10,8];
u = r * cos(theta); % convert polar (theta,r) to cartesian
v = r * sin(theta);
h = quiver(x,y,u,v,'linewidth',2);
set(gca, 'XLim', [2 15], 'YLim', [4 15]);
```

As is clear from the image, in some regions the number of arrows is more than in other places. I want to show the arrows by color, where each color represents the density of the arrows.

Could anyone help me to do that? It would also be a good solution if there is a continuous background color which shows local densities.

Comment: As EBH said on the previous question, you cannot specify the individual arrow colour when using `quiver`. Would something like an underlying contour plot (seen [in this gradient example](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html#bt28nw6-1)) be okay to illustrate density, if the colours were defined by density?

Comment: Yes, if the colors were defined by density everything is ok and the problem is solved @Wolfie

Comment: It is also perfect if there is a background color which shows densities instead of lines @Wolfie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Below are some options for colouring the background of the plot depending on the density of your points. I'm editing this into the top of my answer because it actually answers your question - individually colouring `quiver` arrows based on density!

```
x = rand(200,1)*10; y = rand(200,1)*10;  % Set up random points
r = 1; u = r * cos(x); v = r * sin(y);   % Quiver directions
colormap winter; c = colormap;           % Set colourmap and assign to matrix
% Get density of points broken into a 10x10 grid
[n,~,~,binX,binY] = histcounts2(x,y,[10,10]);      
% Get colour based on histogram density and chosen colormap colours
col = c(ceil(n(sub2ind(size(n), binX, binY))/max(n(:))*size(c,1)),:);
figure; hold on;
% Each quiver point must be plotted individually (slow!) because colours can 
% only be applied to individual quivers. This could be sped up by plotting
% all of the same colour at once.
for ii = 1:size(x,1); 
    quiver(x(ii),y(ii),u(ii),v(ii),0,'color',col(ii,:)); 
end
```

Output:

[image: quiver colours]

**Note**: unlike the below example, you cannot use `hist3` because you need it to return the bin index too. You could try [this File Exchange](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23897-n-dimensional-histogram) function to achieve the same result (untested).

---

Here is an option using [`hist3`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) to get the density (in this example I use a 10x10 grid, as specified when calling `hist3`). Then using `pcolor` to display the density, and [`shading interp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shading.html) to smooth the colours.

*Note: `hist3` requires the Stats & ML toolbox, if you have Matlab 2015b or newer you can instead use the standard function `histcounts2(x,y)`.*

```
% Generate points and quiver directions
x = rand(200,1)*10; y = rand(200,1)*10;
u = r * cos(x); v = r * sin(y);
% Get density of points, format for input to pcolor
n = hist3([x,y],[10,10]);  % Get density of points broken into a 10x10 grid
colx = linspace(min(x),max(x),size(n,1)+1);
coly = linspace(min(y),max(y),size(n,1)+1);
n = n'; n(size(n,2)+1,size(n,1)+1) = 0;
% Plot
figure
pcolor(colx,coly,n)  % Density plot
hold on; colorbar;   % Hold on for next plot and show colour bar key
quiver(x,y,u,v,'r')  % Quiver plot
shading interp       % Smooth plot colours
```

Output:

[image: quiver]

---

Edit: making the colours more muted

You can control the colours using [`colormap`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). This could be one of the defaults, or you can create a custom map of RGB triplets and have whatever colours you want! Here is an example, simply calling `colormap bone;` at the end of the above code:

[image: bone map]

In a custom colour map, you could make the colours even more muted / less contrasting.

Additionally, you can use [`caxis`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) to scale the colour axis of a plot! Simply call

```
caxis([0,2*max(n(:))]);
```

at the end of the above code to double the maximum colour map value. You can tweak the `2` to get desired results:

[image: muted]

Comment: :) Thank you. Is there a way to make background color less sensitive to the density? Because there are lots of colors in the output and it makes one confused

Comment: Sorry, how can I make it more sensitive to the density? In the case I'm simulation, when I use your code, background is all black

Comment: Using which method? You can increase the sampling resolution (using a larger `k` in `hist3([x,y],[k,k]);`) to get greater fidelity, or change the colour scale as already shown. The rest depends on your data...

Answer (score 1):

this looks way less fancy but specifies the arrow color as function of the number of arrows in a certain number of bins of the x-axis

```
close all;
cm=colormap;

theta = [pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2];
r = 0.25; % magnitude (length) of arrow to plot
x = [4,3.5,3.75,4.5,8,10,12]; y = [8.5,8.2,8.3,8,9,10,8];

[n,c]=hist(x,5); %count arroes in bins

u = r * cos(theta); % convert polar (theta,r) to cartesian
v = r * sin(theta);

figure;hold on

for ii=1:numel(n) %quiver bin by bin
if n(ii)>0
if ii==1
wx=find(x<(c(ii)+(c(ii+1) - c(ii))/2)); %Which X to plot
elseif ii==numel(n)
wx=find(x>c(numel(n)-1));
else
wx=find((x>(c(ii)-(c(ii)-c(ii-1))/2)).*(x<(c(ii+1)-(c(ii+1)-c(ii))/2)));
end

indCol=ceil( (size(cm,1)*n(ii)-0) / max(n));%color propto density of arrows %in this bin
col = cm(indCol,:);%color for this bin

h = quiver(x(wx),y(wx),u(wx),v(wx),0,'linewidth',2,'color',col);

end
end

colorbar
caxis([0 max(n)])
```

Comment: Is there a way which makes vectors' colors more sensitive to the density?

Comment: having more vectors XD or play with the colormap

Comment: It is a really good answer. The only problem is that colours change in the form of layers i x axis. Please run below answer

Comment: using `histc` you can specify the bins and make it almost continous

Comment: how can I use both x and y direction? please run below answer.Then the thing I mean becomes clear

Comment: Just one more question. Is there a way which I could put all heads of arrows in blue for example? and the body of arrow shows the density

Comment: unfortunately `quiver` does not allow for that

Comment: Did you run below answer?

Comment: yes. I get the problem. I see two ways but I have not the time to try it out. 1) Define other bins on the y-axis and nest another loop to go through the x and y bins contemporarily. 2) Try to define a grid and get the coordinates of the points in each grid cell. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have time, could you please try them up? I'm very new in matlab and I don't know how to try them